# Implementation Kołmogorow-Smirnow in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a problem with implementing a Kołmogorow-Smirnow test for below problem:

> Let 1, … ,  and 1, … ,  be independent random samples from the distributions (, ^2) and (, ^2) respectively. Consider test with size  = 0.05 for the hypothesis 0:  ≤  against the alternative 1:  >  — the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for stochastic ordering. Draw on a single plot the empirical power curve for  = 60,  = 70,  = 5, ^2 = 1, depending on . Assume  = 4, 4.02, 4.04, … , 6.

Here is my code:

```r
mc <- 10000
MC <- 10000
alpha <- 0.05
mx <- 5  
sigma_sq <- 1  
s <- seq(4, 6, by=0.02)  
MW <- numeric()
MK <- numeric()

for (k in 1:length(s)) {
  for (j in 1:mc) {
    X <- rnorm(60, mx, sqrt(sigma_sq))
    Y <- rnorm(70, s[k], sqrt(sigma_sq))
    nx <- length(X)
    ny <- length(Y)
    Z <- c(X, Y)
    T <- c()
    for (i in 1:nx) {
      T[i] <- -1/nx
    }
    for (i in (nx + 1):(nx + ny)) {
      T[i] <- 1/ny
    }
    V <- cbind(Z, T)
    V <- V[order(V[, 1], decreasing=FALSE), ]
    SP <- cumsum(V[, 2])
    SN <- -cumsum(V[, 2])
    KSP <- max(SP)
    KSN <- max(SN)
    KSPMC <- numeric(MC)
    KSNMC <- numeric(MC)
    for (i in 1:MC) { 
      ZMC <- runif(length(s), 0, 1) 
      TMC <- ifelse(seq_along(s) <= nx, -1/nx, 1/ny) 
      VMC <- cbind(ZMC, TMC) 
      VMC <- VMC[order(VMC[, 1], decreasing=FALSE), ] 
      SPMC <- cumsum(VMC[, 2])
      SNMC <- -cumsum(VMC[, 2])
      KSPMC[i] <- max(SPMC)
      KSNMC[i] <- max(SNMC)
    } 
    MW <- c(MW, mean(KSPMC > KSP))
    MK <- c(MK, mean(KSNMC > KSN))
  }
}

plot(MK, col="blue")
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me correct my code?

By using ks.test I get this red line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERaNC.png

but from my code I get totally different picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/od5SZ.png

Comment: You are aware that R comes with an implementation in `stats::ks.test`?

Comment: yeah, I know, but I want to implement it without ready R's implementation

Comment: Perhaps look at the source code to the R implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but it would be useful for you to edit your question to explain how you know something is wrong with your code. Is it throwing errors or warnings (if so, what are they)?  Are the answers obviously wrong (if so, describe/explain how you know they're wrong)?

Comment: @BenBolker I added graphs